# Error using clientY when vertical scrollbar exists

Tags: javascript

I am trying to popup a div whenever a span with id `toolpopup` is clicked (div should appear at those coordinates) and it works fine for the spans which are at the top of the page. But when i scroll down and click the span the div is created but not at the desired coordinates. What could be possibly wrong? I am trying it on `Firefox 7.0.1`

```
$("#toolpopup").live("click", function(event) {
    var X = event.clientX;
    var Y = event.clientY;
    $("#popup").css('position', 'absolute');
    $("#popup").css("top", Y);
    $("#popup").css("left", X);
    $("#popup").css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that properly understand your task, but may be you need to append into `X` and `Y` a document scroll offset, because:

> MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX:
> **event.clientX**
>
> Returns the horizontal coordinate **within** the application's **client area**
> at which the event occurred

In my code I get scroll offset as:

```
var xOffset=Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollLeft);
var yOffset=Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop,document.body.scrollTop);
```

Then you can set `X` and `Y` as:

```
$("#toolpopup").live("click", function(ev) {
    var X = ev.clientX+xOffset;
    var Y = ev.clientY+yOffset;
```